# Is there a difference in binding energy between a regular material and a doped one?

Tags: condensed-matter, experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

Say Silicon and boron doped silicon. Would the doping affect the binding energy? Could I see this in an XPS spectra?

Answer (score 1):

Doping does not affect the binding energy. If it introduces band bending at the surface, this will change the work function but the measured binding energy does not depend on the work function.

You might be able to see the Boron peaks in the spectrum if the sample is heavily doped.

Be sure to avoid charging effects when emasuring semiconductors.